# Can Protractor be used for Test Driven Development of Angular JS ?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, protractor

Can Protractor be used for Test Driven Development of Angular JS Application ?  Protractor is popularly used as E2E test framework for Angular but can we use it for TDD (Test Driven Development) ?

Answer (score 3):

Protractor should be used only for E2E testing.

For TDD you can switch to [Karma with Jasmine.](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/19)

Also see http://kroltech.com/2013/11/javascript-tdd-with-jasmine-and-karma/

Comment: Thanks . But is there any reason for not to use protractor for TDD .

Answer (score 1):

I use Protractor in my TDD workflow but not for unit tests. I use it for tests similar to integration tests which require interfacing with a running site.

I wouldn't use it for unit tests because it is so much slower than Karma as a test runner and it requires the server to be started.

I wrote a little about [my experiences doing TDD in Angular](http://eerwitt.github.io/2014/06/28/tdd-with-angular/) which shows how I use Protractor vs Karma. I hope it helps.